# dplyr mutate in R - adding a new column depending on sequence of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am having an issue with `mutate` function in `dplyr`.

- I am trying to
  add a new column called `state` depending on the change in one of the column (`V` column). (V column repeat itself with a sequence so each sequence `(rep(seq(100,2100,100),each=96)` corresponds to one dataset in my `df`)

## Error: impossible to replicate vector of size 8064

Here is reproducible example of md `df`:

```
df <- data.frame (
    No=(No= rep(seq(0,95,1),times=84)), 
    AC= rep(rep(c(78,110),each=1),times=length(No)/2), 
    AR = rep(rep(c(256,320,384),each=2),times=length(No)/6), 
    AM =  rep(1,times=length(No)),
    DQ = rep(rep(seq(0,15,1),each=6),times=84),
    V = rep(rep(seq(100,2100,100),each=96),times=4),
    R = sort(replicate(6, sample(5000:6000,96))))

labels  <- rep(c("CAP-CAP","CP-CAP","CAP-CP","CP-CP"),each=2016)
```

I added here `2016` value intentionally since I know the number of rows of each dataset.

But I want to assign these labels with automated function when the dataset changes. Because there is a possibility the total number of rows may change for each `df` for my real files. For this question think about its only one txt file and also think about there are plenty of them with different number of rows. But the format is the same.

I use `dplyr` to arrange my `df`

```
library("dplyr")
newdf<-df%>%mutate_each(funs(as.numeric))%>%
mutate(state = labels)
```

is there elegant way to do this process?

Comment: Please, do fix your code because it is not reproducible.

Comment: Of course if you run that code it works because you have (most likely) defined the `No` object in your workspace, but as you have posted it is not reproducible, in fact it triggers the error `object No not found`. R triggers this error when you say `length(No)/2)`... because we do not have previously defined that `No` object.

Comment: The sample data isn't reproducible because it expects a variable `No` to be defined before the data.frame is created. Why are you doing the `mutate_each(funs(as.numeric))`? You data already appears to be numeric.  How are you mapping the values in your `labels` vector  to the rest of the data.frame?

Comment: back to your problem... with `group_by` you split your data in groups (by AR and AC) and so these subsets must be smaller than the original data set. R does not know how to map `labels` and these subsets, furthermore since `labels` has the same length of the original data, R is confused because it does not know what values to use I guess.

Comment: @MrFlick I just confirmed that `df` is working correctly. for the second issue you mentioned why I use `mutate_each(funs(as.numeric))` that is for my real `.csv` file format. Since I put here reproducible example.

All I want to do is put those labels as a factor for sequenced `V`.

Comment: @SabDeM I couldnt catch what you mean. what I want to do is pretty simple I guess. Please check my previous comment.

Comment: can you switch the order of `group_by` and `mutate` to `... mutate(state = labels) %>% group_by(AR,AC) ...`

Comment: @nongkrong yes no problem you can switch.

Comment: well, if you do switch, there should be no problem I think

Comment: @nongkrong yes no problem but how can I do that with automated way. I mean a function can recognize the change in `V` column dataset and assign the label with new column. I set `2016` value intentionally. Is there a automated way to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your problem.  If you provide an example of the output you want, that might help make it clearer.

Comment: If I group by AR and AC, the resulting groups have 1,344, not the 2,016 I was expecting from your description of the problem. What, if anything, in `df` differentiates values in one data set from another? If there isn't anything, then I don't see how you could automate the assignment like you're asking to do.

Comment: @ulfelder ok forget about grouping. Let's only focus on how to mutate labels with automated function. I revised the problem.

Comment: Again, I don't know how you could do that without knowing how the structure you want the labels to represent is reflected in `df`, and you haven't said anything about that. Which combinations of which variables uniquely identify the subsets you want to label? If the answer to that is "none", then you can't automate this.

Comment: @ulfelder please check top of my question about your inquires.

Comment: Will the data sets you're trying to extract always have the same number of rows as each other, and will you know how many data sets there are in `df`?

Comment: @ulfelder No they won't. There is a possibility the total number of rows may change for each `df`. For this question think about its only one `txt` file and think about there are plenty of them with different number of rows. But the format is the same.

Comment: Will you know the number of data sets contained in `df`, and will `df$V` be ordered in `df` as it is in your example?

Comment: @ulfelder no I couldn't now how many row will be in `df`. But I think we can know by nrow(df) after processing it. and `df$V` is always ordered like in the `df` that I provided here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iff you know the number of data sets contained in `df` AND the column you're keying off --- here, V --- is ordered in `df` like it is in your toy data, then this works. It's pretty clunky, and there should be a way to make it even more efficient, but it produced what I take to be the desired result:

```
# You'll need dplyr for the lead() part
library(dplyr)
# Make a vector with the labels for your subsets of df
labels <- c("AP-AP","P-AP","AP-P","P-P")
# This line a) produces an index that marks the final row of each subset in df
# with a 1 and then b) produces a vector with the row numbers of the 1s
endrows <- which(grepl(1, with(df, ifelse(lead(V) - V < 0, 1, 0))))
# This line uses those row numbers or the differences between them to tell rep()
# how many times to repeat each label
newdf$state <- c(rep(labels[1], endrows[1]), rep(labels[2], endrows[2] - endrows[1]),
    rep(labels[3], endrows[3] - endrows[2]), rep(labels[4], nrow(newdf) - endrows[3]))
```